# How to delete row from specific datatable among multiple datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been using jQuery Datatables and on pages with one table the following code work as it should but on one page I am using tabs and they each have datatable. Their design is set up with

```
var oTable = $('.dataTable').dataTable({....})
```

The problem I have is when I go and try to delete a row in a table other than the first one. Each row as a link with the class = delete so I have a javascript like this

```
$('.delete').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(oTable.fnGetPosition(row));
        });
```

When I try to delete a row from the second table for example it retrieve row = something like 2 and delete the corresponding row in the first table.

I am having trouble thinking of a way to identify the exact oTable. I tried to assign each datatable a numeric id and retrieve it in the click function and id the oTable like this

```
    <table class="table dataTable repsonsive" id="4">

    $('.delete').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            table = $(this).closest("table").attr('id');
            row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
            oTable[table].fnDeleteRow(oTable[table].fnGetPosition(row));
        });
```

I am guessing oTable doesn't work like collection. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i pass data from one datatable to another (im using jquery 1.9)
i assign oTable as a global javascript variable, then my table data as an object declared at the doc ready

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
var passData ={};

   $(document).on("click", "#example tbody tr", function(){

   var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);

   passData =  oTable.fnGetData(aPos);
   });
```

passData is now available throughout my other doc ready event declarations after i have clicked on a row

```
   $('#someDiv').on('click', function(){
    someFunction(passData);
    });
```

For your issue though, which i assume has a delete button on each row,  i was thinking to set position as a variable aPos, global to the document ready, then executing your delete function

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
var passData ={};
var aPos;

   $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){

   aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
   oTable.fnDeleteRow(oTable.fnGetPosition(aPos));

   return false;
   });

});
```

if you are having issue with not knowing which table is which, define them as different variable names

```
var oTable, xTable, yTable, zTable;
```

then call the functions as needed by their declarations

Comment: I tried this but got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined  for aPos

Comment: If I do the second part of your suggestion then I would have tons of repeated line to set up the dataTable settings like     var oTable = $('.dataTable1').dataTable({...20 lines...})   var xTable = $('.dataTable2').dataTable({...20 lines...})

Comment: Ok I get you on that, heres the thing, each tab i assume defines the object oTable again, correct? on click the data is loaded? if thats the case, you would be constantly redefining what the oTable is? From what I'm guessing, each tab has a different dataset, so why shouldnt they have their own declaration?

Comment: as far as aPos is concerned , are you using the most recent datatables 1.9.4? I do not get that error

Comment: Yes it is kind of redefine after each delete with "fnDrawCallback": function(){} in the datatable setting. Also I am using the latest 1.9.4.

Comment: I only have one oTable define for all the tables with class = dataTable like  var oTable = $('.dataTable').dataTable({....}) that's why I thought I could iterate to the right table with oTable[..#int..]

Comment: ok i understand, let me try some different things and ill update my answer when i have a working ver